# messenger bot: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, body-parser

I used node.js to implement a chat bot for facebook messenger. During testing I had no problems or errors. But after I uploaded the node.js webhook to a verified facebook developers app, I am getting the above error. Everything is working fine in my chatbot. People are getting replies from my dialogflow agent. But if i check my heroku logs i see "Cannot read property error". Why am i seeing this error when everything is working fine? During testing i did not get this error. I have checked other questions in stackoverflow aswell. I also updated everything using npm update, according to one of the answers in stackoverflow, but it did not help. Here is where my error originates from:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
const uuid = require('uuid');
const pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: verifyRequestSignature
}));

//serve static files in the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  // Make sure this is a page subscription
  if (data.object == 'page') {
    // Iterate over each entry
    // There may be multiple if batched
    data.entry.forEach(function (pageEntry) {
      var pageID = pageEntry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = pageEntry.time;
      console.log("pageentery:" + pageEntry);
      console.log("messaging:" + pageEntry.messaging);
      // Iterate over each messaging event
      pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function (messagingEvent) {

        if (messagingEvent.optin) {
          receivedAuthentication(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.message) {
          receivedMessage(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.delivery) {
          receivedDeliveryConfirmation(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.postback) {
          receivedPostback(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.read) {
          receivedMessageRead(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.account_linking) {
          receivedAccountLink(messagingEvent);
        } else {
          console.log("Webhook received unknown messagingEvent: ", messagingEvent);
        }
      });
    });
    // Assume all went well.
    // You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});
```

So, I am getting this error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" on pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function (messagingEvent) {..}.

Comment: Because, the value of `pageEntry.messaging` is either not an array or nullish. `.forEach` is available for array.

Comment: Check array type with Array.isArray https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray then use `.forEach` otherwise, handle the error case

Answer (score 0):

properly handle the null and undefined cases

```
let messagingEventCallback=(messagingEvent)=>{
..............
your code base
.................
}
let pageEntryMessage=pageEntry.messaging;
(pageEntryMessage && pageEntryMessage instanceOf Array)?pageEntryMessage.forEach(messagingEventCallback):console.log(`Message is not Array ${pageEntryMessage}`);
```

Comment: The error is not showing up anymore. It was something to do with facebook's developer app permissions. Thanks anyway